# Who are the people killed right before the team meets the imprisoned creature?

Tags: plot-explanation, love-death-and-robots

In Love, Death and Robots Season 3, Ep `In Vaulted Halls Entombed`, a group of special force soldiers go into a cave and see a huge platform where a Cthulu-like creature is prisoned.

Right before the final two team members go down the steps, the team leader shoots two other people who are already on the platform.

I am wondering who they are? As it has been established earlier that all insurgents and the hostage have been eaten by spiders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Not all insurgents have been killed

Initially, Special Forces finds a body of the hostage and a few bodies of the insurgents, all eaten by the "spiders". But then, when they find themselves surrounded by those creatures, you can hear in the background a machine gun fire. This means, that some insurgents have survived the initial attack and have run deeper into the cave.